# How to refer to a variable in the Shapiro test?

Tags: r, variables

I would like to ask you about shapiro test in R. How can I refer to a variable in test result?

```
r<-shapiro.test(reszty)
r

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  reszty
W = 0.9226, p-value = 4.967e-07
```

I would like to refer to w and to p-value.

Comment: `names(shapiro.test(reszty))` should help.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: Simply save and access `a <- shapiro.test(rnorm(100, mean = 5, sd = 3)); a$p.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for function calls in R you can extract information after assigning to a variable doing this:

```
r<-shapiro.test(reszty)
r$statistic (for W) or r$p.value (for p-val)
```

or you can not assign to a variable, but extract straight away:

```
shapiro.test(reszty)$p.value
```